# How to create/write and read word(having .doc and .docx extensions) file in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, apache-poi, kotlin-android-extensions

I need to write/read word file, also if there is any third party please let me know.
I used this code to create file ->

```
fun createFile(fileName: String): File? {

    val APP_NAME = "Sample App"
    val LOCAL_STORAGE_BASE_PATH_FOR_MEDIA = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + APP_NAME
    val storageDirPath: String = "$LOCAL_STORAGE_BASE_PATH_FOR_MEDIA/User/Docs/"
    val TEXT_FILE_PREFIX = "Word_"
    val TEXT_FILE_SUFFIX = ".docx"   //even I used .doc extension too

    var wordFile: File? = null
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED == Environment
                    .getExternalStorageState()) {
        val storageDir = File(storageDirPath)
        if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
            if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory")
                return null!!
            }
        }
        wordFile = if (fileName.isEmpty()) {
            File.createTempFile(TEXT_FILE_PREFIX + System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    TEXT_FILE_SUFFIX, storageDir)
        } else {
            File.createTempFile(TEXT_FILE_PREFIX
                    + fileName,
                    TEXT_FILE_SUFFIX, storageDir)
        }
    }
    return wordFile
}
```

and using this function I write in the file

```
private fun writeToFile() {
    val docFile = createFile()
    try {
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(docFile)
        val outputStreamWriter = OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream)
        outputStreamWriter.append(etSpeechArea.text.toString().trim())

        outputStreamWriter.close()
        fileOutputStream.flush()
        fileOutputStream.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString())
    }

}
```

the file is being created and written but when it is being opened using any word software or app it is showing that file format is invalid. Can someone tell what am I missing while creating file?

Comment: I don't know if Apache POI works on Android, but it is pretty much the only bet.

Comment: https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android might help